# Pluck associated model's attribute in Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

In my rails app, **collections** have many **projects**, and projects have many **steps**.

I'd like to grab all the ids of steps in a collection's projects, and I'm wondering if I can do it all in one query.

For example, I know I can do the following

```
step_ids = []
@collection.projects.each do |project|
    project.steps.each do |step|
       step_ids << step.id
    end
end
```

But is it possible to do something like the following:

`@collection.projects.include(:steps).pluck("step.id")` // syntax here is not correct

Comment: Inside `Collection` you can also add `has_many :steps, through: :projects` to simplify `collection.steps.pluck(:id)`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
Step.joins(:project).where(projects: { collection_id: @collection.id }).pluck(:'steps.id')
```

Note the use of `project` for the joins, and then `projects` for the where clause. The first corresponds to the belongs_to relationship, and the latter is the name of the db table.

edit: in the case of a many-to-many relationship between projects and collections, and assuming a project belongs_to a project_collection (and then `has_many :collections, through :project_collection`)

```
Step.joins(:project => :project_collection)
    .where(project_collections: { collection_id: @collection.id })
    .pluck(:'steps.id')
```

Comment: thanks for your help. projects can actually belong to multiple collections, so there is no collection_id attribute for projects.  any ideas for how to change your suggestion?

Comment: is there a `projects_collections` table then? You can extend the join to encompass it....I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: I know it's late but is it better to use symbol `:'steps.id'` like you do rather than as a string `'steps.id'`?

Comment: @244an it's a very minor optimization to create fewer objects. Nowadays, using the `# frozen_string_literal: true` pragma is the more common way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that we could do it through AR in a single query. You could do a nested query below to retrieve it in two queries to the database:

```
Step.includes(:projects)
    .where(projects: { id: Projects.includes(:collections)
    .where(collections: { id: @collections.id }).pluck(:id) } )
    .pluck(:id)
```